# Adding a base prefix to Neo4j bolt port

Tags: docker, https, neo4j, cypher

currently we are using a proxy server to route our spring application to a https url however we also want to do this with our Neo4j instance. 
This requires us to change the base prefix url to allow us to properly route the ports (bolt port and the browser port). Side note we are running Neo4j in a Docker image.

In case my above explanation was unclear I have included an example of what we would like to do and what is currently happening.

Currenly the Neo4j browser resolves to this url:
http://(ip_address):7474/browser/
We would like to have it resolve to:
http://(ip_address):7474/Neo4j/browser/

Currently the Neo4j bolt port resolves to: 
bolt://(ip_address):7687 
We would like to have it resolve to:
bolt://(ip_address):7687/Neo4j/

Any idea on how we can configure this?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint that the Neo4J browser is accessed at (`/browser`) cannot, to my knowledge, be configured to be at another location out of the box, nor can this be changed in the configuration file.

You may be able to do this by modifying Neo4J itself, or by changing your proxy settings such that any and all request to it at `/Neo4J/browser/` are re-written on the fly to `/browser` from the docker container's perspective, but this will not work if you intend on also using HTTPS (unless you also Man-in-the-Middle the certs, which is usually not best practices), but that would be a unique situation and it will be outside the realm of typical Neo4J ops/configuration.

Comment: In the end this is also what I concluded, we managed to route to /browser however since neo4j also needs the bolt port we also need to add a base prefix or a context path to that 7687 port. Any ideas on that front. We would rather not mod neo4j directly cause we would have to it any subsequent releases of neo4j.

Comment: Is there a certain setting with your proxy such that you have to have an endpoint for the bolt port? Routing a path to a port doesn't really make any sense... Bolt does not have "endpoints", that's a feature uniquely limited to certain text-based protocols such as HTTP. Usually the way I see that kind of routing done with ports is by mapping ports to other ports; e.g. map :1337 on the proxy to go to :7687 on the destination server.